# clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 while installing Faunus

Tags: c++, cmake, clang, openmp, tbb

I am installing Faunus (https://github.com/mlund/faunus) on Debian 10, where I do not have sudo privileges.

I have installed LLVM 12 to get CLANG/CLANG++ and Intel's TBB, locally. The CMAKE build command is shown below:

```
$CC=$HOME/llvm/bin/clang CXX=$HOME/llvm/bin/clang++ cmake -B build -DCMAKE_CXX_FLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ -DCMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-stdlib=libc++ -DENABLE_OPENMP=ON -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX:PATH="..." -DZLIB_LIBRARY=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so
```

I am using CMAKE 3.20 and Anaconda3 for python. Before CMAKE, I am exporting compiler flags as:

```
$export LDFLAGS="-L$HOME/llvm/lib $LDFLAGS"; export CFLAGS="-I$HOME/llvm/include $CFLAGS"; export CC=$HOME/llvm/bin/clang; export CXX=$HOME/llvm/bin/clang++

$cmake --build build
```

exits with

```
[ 98%] Building CXX object src/CMakeFiles/faunus.dir/faunus.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX executable ../faunus
/usr/bin/ld: CMakeFiles/faunus.dir/faunus.cpp.o: in function `createProgressTracker(bool, unsigned int)': faunus.cpp:(.text+0xcc6f): undefined reference to `ProgressIndicator::ProgressBar::ProgressBar(unsigned int, std::__1::basic_ostream<char, std::__1::char_traits<char> >&, unsigned int, char, char)'

clang-12: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation).
```

Then I included Cmake BOOL option on, which shows many times -std=gnu++17 instead of -std=c++17. It seems that cmake is not passing some of library flags to the linker. Is this the problem of cmake OR the files related to cmake in this project?

The CMakeLists.text is shown below:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16 FATAL_ERROR)

project(faunus)
include(cmake/StandardProjectSettings.cmake)
include(cmake/CPM.cmake)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED YES)
set(CMAKE_CXX_EXTENSIONS YES)

# Interface library for all Faunus targets
add_library(project_options INTERFACE)
target_compile_features(project_options INTERFACE cxx_std_17)

# Link this 'library' to use the warnings specified in CompilerWarnings.cmake
add_library(project_warnings INTERFACE)

# Enable cache system
include(cmake/Cache.cmake)

include(cmake/CompilerWarnings.cmake)
set_project_warnings(project_warnings)

set(THREADS_PREFER_PTHREAD_FLAG ON)
find_package(PythonInterp 3 REQUIRED)
find_package(Threads REQUIRED)
find_package(ZLIB REQUIRED)
enable_testing()

include(cmake/CompilerFlags.cmake)
include(cmake/ExternalTools.cmake)
include(cmake/GITversion.cmake)

add_subdirectory(src)
add_subdirectory(docs)
add_subdirectory(examples)
```

Can I ask for help in this regard?

Thanking you in anticipation!!

Comment: It's a bit weird. The `ProgressIndicator::ProgressBar` class seems like it would be imported from "progress_tracker.h". Since no such file exists in the repository I assume it's a third-party package, but I have no idea which. Your compilation works so I assume you _do_ have this header, but you didn't link against this library.

Comment: Thank you @unddoch. I have checked it, the third party source is  https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/+/refs/heads/main/third_party/blink/renderer/core/loader/progress_tracker.h . This is Apple's product. But, the strange thing is that I could install it on my laptop with CLANG12. Only the difference is that in cluster, I am installing Clang, TBB, etc., locally.

Comment: It felt weird so I double-checked - it's a fork by the same author @ https://github.com/mlund/progress-cpp. It is installed through the cmake/External tools.cmake script. Can you check if the shared library was compiled at libprogresstracker.a?

Comment: @unddoch Thanks a lot for double checking. I googled it found the other one instead of the fork by the same author. I have checked the shared library was compiled at libprogresstracker.a.

Comment: Can you find out the linker command that cmake uses to link the executable? Also, run `nm -C libprogresstracker.a | grep ProgressBar` to see if the function is there.